# How to disable or change MySQL Fulltext stopwords for single user on SHARED server?

Tags: mysql, innodb, stop-words, mybb

I want to disable stopwords in search on MySQL fields with fulltext indexes in my database (table type InnoDB, for a MyBB forum), but am on a SHARED server at a hosting company.

All of the instructions on how to disable stopwords, or change the default server built-in list to one's own table, require using the GLOBAL command and rebooting the server - neither of which I can do as a user on a shared server. Is there a reliable way to do this as a user on a shared server? I've tried the following with no luck:

Following other posts, I was able to go in to cPanel > PHPMyAdmin> and using SQL Queries, create a "user_stopwords" table:

```
CREATE TABLE mybb_stopwords(value VARCHAR(30)) ENGINE = INNODB;
INSERT INTO mybb_stopwords(value) VALUES ('stopword1');
```

But the only way I could actually instruct MySQL to use that table was if I entered the following lines in a SINGLE query - and it worked, but only for the SESSION.

```
set session innodb_ft_user_stopword_table='database/mybb_stopwords';
alter table mybb_posts engine=innodb;
alter table mybb_threads engine=innodb;
```

As soon as the session is over, it reverts back to using the GLOBAL server stopword list...

Next, I tried variations of the following in the user-level my.cnf preference file, which my hosting provider tells me gets read every few hours for user-level preferences - but with no effect:

```
[mysql]                 ... or mysqld ...
ft_stopword_file = ""   ...or...
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table="database/mybb_stopwords"
```

But no combination of the above works - whenever I check with this:

```
show variables like 'ft_%';
```

It replies

```
ft_stopword_file: (built in)
```

The MySQL documentation (my host's server is v5.6) says you can put user-level preferences in the my.cnf file and they should work - am I just not getting the syntax right? Or perhaps a User can't set a user-level preference for stopwords on a shared server?

Answer (score 0):

Even better...

> To create stopword lists on a table-by-table basis, create other stopword tables and use the innodb_ft_user_stopword_table option to specify the stopword table that you want to use before you create the full-text index.

-- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

Be sure to use `SET SESSION sysvar_innodb_ft_user_stopword_table = ...` if you want it to apply until logging out.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_user_stopword_table

Since the only choices are `GLOBAL` and `SESSION`, it cannot be set for a `DATABASE` or 'user'.

Comment: Yes I tried, but I can't do the "Set GLOBAL..." because I'm just a user on a shared server... hence my question, how to set the stopwords as a SINGLE USER on a SHARED server - where I don't have rights/access to reboot the server, or set Global variables.... The same dev.mysql.com documentation says that user preferences can be set via the user-level my.cnf file... but nothing actually works. So do I have the syntax wrong in the my.cnf file, OR... is it simply NOT possible to set stopwords for a user... I can't get anything that lasts more than a "session" which is useless. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suggest filling a "feature request" via bugs.mysql.com .

Comment: Stopword are words that MySQL don't search as they are very common. But basicly, the Stopword list is in English... To deal with the problem of language AND the problem of Shared Server, a basic option is to create your own stopword table. When the user enter the sentence he's searching for, just delete all the words from this sentence that are in your stopword table and then perform the search with the words which still are in the sentence.

Comment: That is, have two text columns:  One for display, One for indexing.